# How can I set my root directory based on a cookie?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm attempting to use my htaccess file to set my root folder based on a cookie that is set through the website. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any information on how to do this. Here is what I have tried doing, which I know is incorrect, but it was the best I could find to work with.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.(int|com)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/s3i.flat/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} s=n2014 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /s3i.flat/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /s3i.2014/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.(int|com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} s=n2014 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ s3i.flat/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ s3i.2014/ [L]
```

What I'm trying to do is use the `s3i.flat` directory if the cookie named `s` is equal to `n2014`, and the other directory if the cookie is not set, or does not equal that. Is anyone aware of a way that this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else out there would like the answer to this question, I've finally figured it out. Here is what I have come up with that successfully works. If anyone has any modifications to make this better, please let us know.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.(int|com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} s=n2014 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /s3i.flat/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /s3i.2014/$1 [L]
```

For those wondering, I use `int` as my TLD for local building. If you don't do that, simply replace `(int|com)` with just `com`. As for the rest:

My particular cookie name is `s`, and the value is `n2014`. You can replace each of those with your own values. This part of the code is looking to see if that cookie exists. The third line is telling the site to use the `s3i.flat` directory as my root directory if the cookie exists, and the fourth line is telling the site to use the `s3i.2014` directory if the cookie does not exist.

Just replace everything with your own values, and it should work properly. Again, if anyone can build on this, or has a suggestion to make it better, please let us know!